# Using ssh keys when one can not store anything on the jump host

Tags: ssh

So I have the following "problem". I have a work laptop I want to ssh into my workstation. However, due to security measures I have to first log into a jump host before being able to login.

```
ssh -J -A username@jumphost username@workstation-name
```

This is fine, however this means I have to input my password twice; once for the jump host and one for my computer.

I can not store any ssh keys on the jump host as it is locked down, however I can store keys on my workstation and laptop.

Is there any way I can manage to login with just inputting a single password and do the rest with validated keys?

Comment: (1) Do you mean "password" (to authenticate) or "passphrase" (to unlock your key)? If unsure, see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1576115/432690). The passphrase and the password are different concepts. You wrote "password" but in the context of keys maybe you mean "passphrase". (2) "I can not store any ssh keys on the jump host as it is locked down" – But is your public key *already* in the `authorized_keys` there?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do that with `AgentForwarding`.
You first need to add your local key to the `ssh-agent`, and then forward it with `ssh -oForwardAgent=yes -J jmpserver workstation`.
Probably you are missing the first step.

Although, the option must be enabled in your jump server and you may have to setup correctly your local client to share the keys. The very verbose flag (`-vv`) of `ssh` may help to determine if it is working or not.

See the [GitHub tutorial](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/overview/using-ssh-agent-forwarding) for some instructions.